# I can't understand what your point is or I can't understand what is your point?

Tags: grammar

What is correct way to say:

> I can't understand what your point is?

or

> I can't understand what is your point?

Answer (score 2):

> I can't understand what your point is?
>
> I can't understand what is your point?

You have question marks for both of those. However telling someone that you don't understand is not a question, it is a statement. So the first thing to do is remove the question marks.

> I can't understand what your point is.
>
> I can't understand what is your point.

The former is the normal word order in English for a statement so that is the correct version.

**Afterthought**

In fact it can be a question if split into two, i.e.

> I can't understand. What is your point?

or perhaps

> I don't understand. What is your point?

Comment: Yes; note also that the more usual thing to say in this context is "But what's your point?", "So what's your point?", or "And your point is...?"